# Issue with Google Font API

Tags: html, css, google-font-api, google-fonts

I can't get my Google Font API to bring up the font I'm selecting. Got the links straight from Google, CSS seems right, but no joy. Am I doing something wrong?

HTML:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 900;
}
title {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

  <!-- Google Font API -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;700;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;700;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap'); </style>

  <!-- CSS Connection -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>
<body>

<h1>Heading H1</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Tried changing the quotations from " to ' and even `. Tried changing the name of the font to Montserrat-black, tried all sorts of solutions around the internet.

Comment: I converted your code to a snippet so you can run it here - it seems to work fine.  What exactly is the problem? Note you have CSS for `title`, but that's not an element you can style - it's an element in the header.  If you meant it to be a class, like `.title`, and use it like `<p class='title'>`, that also works fine.

Comment: So the issue is that when I try to load the page with that h1, it won't change at all. None of the CSS seems to take effect. BTW, thanks for the tip with the title!

Comment: What does your browser's devtools show? Are the font refs really loading? In devtools, if you select an `h1` element, can you see the font being applied?  Is it being overriden by something?  It works fine here, so it must be either something else in code you haven't shown, or something in your local environment, eg something blocking loading those remote fonts ... ?  Your browser devtools will show you.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks, I'll look at the devtools once I get back home and update you!

Comment: @Don'tPanic I found the issue! It was the text that was inserted ina div, which I found in the devtools like you said, once I changed the h1 css to a div class, it worked! Thanks for the help!